# how to record audio without flash and java from browser and upload to server

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I want to upload the audio from user to server. How can i do it from browser itself. My main application is browser based. I am looking for browser and non browser based solution but It should be Open Source. That is why i put "without flash" in subject. With Java applet user will face problem in installing jre !! is there any hope that in near future browser will support such feature. Do we have any addon in firefox which can help in this regard.

Comment: Do you really want the user to record their audio with a browser-based solution or are you more concerned with just the upload of the final audio product?

Comment: @Beck Record and Upload.

Answer (score 1):

What is the requirement for Open Source specifically relating to? There are open source/free software ways to produce flash content for the browser. You aren't tied to the Adobe Flash IDE.

Look into these products:

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org)

[Adobe Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk) (Free download)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this question, there wasn't a way to do this. Today we can use html5 and the GetUserMedia function for the main browsers (safari is the exception) . There are many articles and examples on that subject.
One good example can be found here:

http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html